# Ng-click Angular JS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In my view

```
<button type="button"
                ng-disabled="isProcessing"
                ng-click="login.ssoFacebook()"
                class="button button-primary">
                <span class="icon icon-social-facebook"></span>
                Login Using Facebook
            </button>
```

When I click the button facebook doesn't work 
My controller

```
this.ssoFacebook = function(){
        // intiate
        ssoAuth.facebook.initiate()
        .then(function(customer){
            if (!customer) throw 'error system';

            authService.setCurrentSession(customer, $scope);
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.$emit(GLOBAL_EVENTS.SYSTEM.ACCOUNT.SESSION.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
            }, 500);
            // redirect or something
            $state.go('products', {}, {reload: true});
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            $scope.$emit(GLOBAL_EVENTS.SYSTEM.ACCOUNT.SESSION.LOGIN_FAILED, error);
        });
    };
```

Am I doing something wrong? thanks advance

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Show full controller's code please.

Comment: can you post some more code? include the definition of your controller please

Comment: @Kamo it doesn't show pop up facebook authenticate, this is my full code controller [http://plnkr.co/edit/qMI6v34lDklhQmnKvoDs?p=catalogue]

Comment: can you provide how you define `login` in html? For woking like this with controller somewhere above you should declare `ng-controller="Mycontroller as login"`

Comment: Perhaps it is best to public the complete relevant html, including the ng-controller declaration and your complete controller with only the relevant function apprehended. Maybe you could actually provide more details about the nature of your error, what is your console printing and is there any network activity ongoing? So we can exclude the silly mistake of linking the desired function with your html.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code,

```
this.ssoFacebook = function(){
...
}
```

with,

```
$scope.login = {};
$scope.login.ssoFacebook = function(){
..
}
```

This may be the issue.

Comment: @did you debug your click?

Answer (score 1):

If you want use function from controller instead of scope, you need mark this in html in [attribute *ng-controller*](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)

```
ng-controller="ControllerName as login"
```

and below you can use

```
<button type="button"
            ng-disabled="isProcessing"
            ng-click="login.ssoFacebook()"
            class="button button-primary">
            <span class="icon icon-social-facebook"></span>
            Login Using Facebook
</button>
```

Comment: This is actually the only complete answer.

Comment: @skubski, but seems OP already use it and error somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Change your ng-click to 
`ng-click="ssoFacebook()"`

and in your controller change with :

`$scope.ssoFacebook = function(){
...
}`

Comment: This still wouldn't work if there is no declaration of the `ng-controller` attribute.